# MSSQL Select column values from one table to another table

Tags: mysql, sql-server

How to retrive table(B) column values based on table(A) Primary key column value?in MSSQL

**Table(A)**

> ID int PRIMARY KEY
>
> NAME varchar(20)
>
> Role_Id int

**Table(B)**

> Role_Id int PRIMARY KEY,
>
> Role_Type varchar(20).

I am confused about how to retrieve a column(**Role_Type**) values from Table(**B**) to  Table(**A**) by column(**ID**).

*Example,*

**Table(A)**

> ID =1,2,3.
>
> NAME =john,joe,raj.

**Table(B)**

> Role_Id =11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18.
>
> Role_Type =A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H.

If i select **ID=1** then i need below answer,

> ID: 1
>
> NAME: john
>
> Role_Type: A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H

Comment: mysql or (MS) SQL-Server? Also what have you tried?

Comment: You need a Mapping Table (Table C) That Maps ID and Role_Id. Or You Can add a new Column in Table A , say Role_Id.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be *any* way that the data in these two tables can be correlated. So I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: First few things to note 1. It does not make much sense to set a primary key as foreign key too, since a foreign key column is meant to have duplicates and primary key is unique. 2. Here there is no relation between ID from table A and Role_Id from Table B; as mentioned by @Sahi you need to change your design

Comment: if i map Role_Id(Table(A)) to Role_Id(Table(B)).i cannot got my required answer.@Sahi

Comment: Any idea have please suggest me.Thanks@Sahi

Comment: SQL-Server.I tried to map Role_Id(Table(A)) to Role_Id(Table(B)) but it not works!!@Jens

Comment: How did you determine that john is associated with all roles from A to H? According to your structure, each person identified in TABLE(A) (in this case john) has on role ID, but according to your desired results, they have 8. If it is really that they need 8, then you need to remove RoleID from Table A and create a new table that has the A.ID and the B.RoleID,and then you would list all the combinations in that table.

Comment: okay.Thanks@Alan

Comment: Thanks for your's feedback@SamuelAC

Comment: What SQL query have you tried?

Comment: select RoleType from B where(select * from A where ID=1);@CurseStacker

Comment: @R.Gopalakrishnan.. let us know, role types in talbe(A).!!

Comment: table(A) contains ID,NAME....table(B) Contains RoleId,RoleType@IdontKnowEnglish

Comment: Table(B)    Role_Type varchar(20) @IdontKnowEnglish

Comment: @R.Gopalakrishnan. I mean, what are the values of `Role_Id ` in table(A)..?

Comment: if i set value of Role_Id values in Table then i cannot got my required result.so i need how to set many to many  relation in my table@IdontKnowEnglish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is you have table A that have Role_Id colum.

ID int PRIMARY KEY

NAME varchar(20)

Role_Id int

That means that you will be only able to related one role to records on table A.

I think you need either to reformulated the question or create a new table C as a many to many relationship between table A and B that way you could have multiples Roles for the records on table A.

like:
Table C
Id
Role_Id

Check the Microsoft reference for many to many relationship.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/define-a-many-to-many-relationship-and-many-to-many-relationship-properties?view=sql-server-2017